# Locating elements in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I have tried to locate button in my web app using xpath but it changes automatically each time I open selenium IDE. Is there any other way to locate it except using xpath or position? can I locate it using class name? If yes then how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Could you please post it so people here can help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to find element by class name.

```
//*[@class='someClass']
```

where, `someClass` is the class name of your element.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your webapp, consider adding an `id` or a `name` to uniquely identify the element. It also makes the xpaths easier to write as you don't need to consider the possibility where you might be grabbing too many elements.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - If by default recorded xpath are not working for your application, then you can define your own xpath for those components which should remain same throughout execution.

Please refer below URL which shows ways to develop userdefined xpath :-

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS selector. This site really helped me: http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

if it has an id on it you can just say "id=yourid"

for css it could be something like this: "css=button[class*='yourclass']" <-- that says it's a button, and that in class it contains yourclass.